# Is the following set topology?

Tags: general-topology

Consider a potential topology $T$ on $\mathbb R^3$ (three dimension space.) $T$ contains sets $$\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq r\},$$ where $r\in\mathbb R^{\geq 0}.$

Since we know that that arbitrary union of open sets is open, suppose I take union of all open sets $s \in T$ such that $(x,y,z)$ follows $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ r$ and $r ∈ (0,1)$. Does the resultant set from union belongs to $T$ ? Since overall radius of sphere formed cannot be $1$ in this case but cannot be strictly less than $1$.

Comment: Do you mean $x^2+y^2+z^2<r$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh sorry  .I edited the question , it will be less than or equal to else it willl be trivial

Comment: You are correct. If $B_r$ is the ball defined, then $\bigcup_{r\in(0,1)} B_r$ is not in $T$.

Comment: More generally, of course, a topology on $\mathbb R^3$ needs to contain the whole set $\mathbb R^3$ and the empty set $\emptyset,$ which $T$ does not. But if you added those sets to $T$ you are argument correctly shows that $T$ is still not a topology.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  in this case $$\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq r\},$$ is empty for $r=0$ and for infinite union over all $r$ it is $R^3$  , then how they do not belong to $T$ ?

Comment: @Faser it is not empty for $r=0$ because it contains the point $(0, 0, 0)$.

Comment: @Faser Actually, that set is not empty, it is $\{(0,0,0)\}$ when $r=0.$ The question is whether $T$ as defined is a topology, not whether it is the basis for some topology.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano Yeah thanks  , i am still stuck to my original post   ;)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks

Comment: Also, at this point you should be clearer about the kind of sets which are contained in $T$, namely offering a complete description of it. Do you mean that the sets of that kind are also the only sets contained in $T$?

Comment: By the way, in the original post, you said the space was $R^3$ (three dimension space.)  Then later you said $r\in R$, where $R$ is the non-negative reals. Did you mean these to be the same $R,$ or is my edit correct? (This doesn't really affect the answer/)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews your topology is correct

Comment: @NikiDiGiano yes .But even if i explicitly include empty set to $T$  then also as Thomas said it will be not a topology .

Comment: Well, a set of subsets of $\Bbb{R}^3$ can contain those sets you describe and still be a topology. Consider the case in which it only contains sets of the form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < r$ and $\leq r$ and also $\mathbb R^3$. If it contains **only** the ones with $\leq$, it is of course not.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why we need to prove that empty set belongs to topology $T$ , since we know that empty set is subset of every set ?

Comment: @NikiDiGiano  Why we need to prove that empty set belongs to topology $T$ , since we know that empty set is subset of every set ?

Comment: @Faser Just because $U\in T$ is in a topolgy and $V\subseteq U,$ we cannot conclude that $V\in T.$ So you have to explicitly add the empty set (and the whole set) to $T,$ (It is true that $\emptyset\subseteq T,$ but it is not necessarily true that $\emptyset\in T.$)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh . i got what you are saying .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument correctly shows that if $T$ consists of the sets $B_r=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\leq r\}$ for $r\in\mathbb R^{\geq 0},$ and the empty set $\emptyset$ and the whole set $\mathbb R^3,$ then $T$ is not a topology because:

$$\bigcup_{r\in(0,1)} B_r=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2<1\}$$

is a union of elements of $T$ which is not in $T.$

The smallest topology $T'$ on $\mathbb R^3$ containing $T$ has the following definition:

> Given subset $U\subseteq \mathbb R^3,$ then $U\in T'$ if and only if, for all $(x,y,z)\in U$ and all $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in\mathbb R^3$ with $x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2\leq x^2+y^2+z^2$, you have that $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in U.$

Alternatively, this can be written as:

> $U\in T'$ if and only if $U\in T$ or $U=U_r=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2<r\}$ for some $r\in\mathbb R^{>0}.$

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is a topology on$\Bbb{R^3}$ that contains a set of the form $\{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < r\}$ for every real number $r$ then the union you describe is the set $\{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1\}$ which is contained in $T$ by the property stated above.

EDIT: this answer is deprecated as it replies to an unedited version of the question.

Comment: OP changed the question to $\leq r.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yeah .Sorry Niki Di Giano , i typed wrong  but corrected when Andrews reminded me